# Размытые текстуры при запуске игры с Unity на телефон

Tags: unity3d, ui, 2d

Делаю свою игру на Unity 2D и в какой-то момент времени решил посмотреть как она будет выглядеть на телефоне. При помощи приложения Unity Remote начал трансляцию игры однако заметил что все UI элементы размытые. Смотрел гайды, читал документации и т.п
вроде как перепробовал всё.
Прошу помочь с проблемой, заранее спасибо
скрины с эмулятора и с приложения unity remote*[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для разнообразия почитай чё такое Unity Remote и почему это не способ проверки, как игра выглядит или ведет себя на телефоне. Хотя не нужно быть гением, что бы догадаться, как она работает.